# Pointers inside struct error in C " 'struct.pointer' '.' unexpected "

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, struct

Got this struct:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned long index;

    void(*function)();
} program;
```

and when i try to access the 2nd field i get this:

```
error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before '.' token in program.callNext = next
```

next is a function declare before:

```
void next() {
    // code
}
```

**EDIT:**

full code:

```
typedef unsigned char bool;

#define true 1
#define false 0 

void next() {
    //useless code
}

typedef void(*function)();    

typedef struct {
    unsigned long index;
    bool running;

    function callNext;
} program;

program shell;

shell.running = true;
shell.index = 0;
shell.callNext = next;
```

gcc don't recognice bool type so i've added it

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem.

Comment: Do you have a variable named `program`?

Comment: `prog.c:9:5: error: unknown type name ‘bool’`

Comment: @melpomene explained at the end of the edit segment

Comment: The error message doesn't match any code you posted. The error says `program.function`, but the code has `shell.callNext`.

Comment: @Shawn no, program is the name of the new type i've defined. then i've instanciated it and call the field shell

Comment: @WeatherVane just done. Sorry accidentally pressed del while posting ...

Comment: Why would gcc "recognize" `bool` as a type? The boolean type in C is called `_Bool`.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with pointers, structs, or gcc. The problem is that you can't have statements outside of functions in C.

Answer (score 1):

When you use write `typedef struct` program become the name of the struct, not an instance. Just remove the `typedef` and it will work.

Comment: i know it should be like this so that i can instanciate differents programs